# math, coordinates

Tags: java, math, coordinate-systems

now i making some problem with JAVA, but don't remember how get lenght between to coordinate-system.

Ex.
point A (3,7)
Point B (7,59)

I want to know how count distance between point a and b. very thanks for your answers. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A = (xa, ya), B = (xb, yb)

Assuming you want euclidean distance ("natural" distance):

distance = sqrt((xa - xb)^2 + (ya - yb)^2).

Comment: Would be nice to give an example in Java.

Comment: @fredley: I don't do Java. Feel free to add whatever you want to my answer. But seriously is this so hard to implement by yourself ???

Answer (score 1):

pythagoras gave that answer

```
sqrt(((A.X - B.X) * (A.X - B.X)) + (((A.Y - B.Y) * (A.Y - B.Y)));
```